# FireFox button to open a specific URL with a parameter?

Tags: firefox

I'm looking for a way to write "xyz" in FireFox, and when I press a button, a URL of the form "http://www.something.com?ID=xyz" will open.
How Do I do that?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add this line as a bookmarklet in Firefox

```
javascript:window.location.href=document.location.href+'?ID=xyz'
```

When on a page, click on the bookmark and '?ID=xyz' will be appended to the URL